# SqlException.Number one value but two different documentations. How?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to implement fault tolerance and trying to collect a list of SQL error numbers that are considered transient. but I keep running into error numbers that have multiple documentations.

Consider error number **10053**:

(1) `A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server` (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues#error-10053-a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server))

(2) `Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.`
(from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-10000-to-10999))

It gets weirder. Consider error number **11001**:

(1) `Non-NULL value successfully returned.`

(2) `An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server....`

Both from the same Microsoft docs [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-11000-to-12999) adjacent to each other.

What's going on?

Comment: Different subsystems. 10053 "a transport-level error..." is `WSAECONNABORTED`, which is generated by the TCP/IP stack, not SQL Server. If you have an `SqlException`, check its `Errors` property; errors produced by SQL Server itself can be distinguished by looking for an `SqlError` where the state is not 0 (although this is not 100% reliable, as technically a true SQL engine error could have such a state), as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number#remarks). `Source` might also be usable, although its contents are not formally documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jeroen Mostert said,
Error 10053 means that an established connection has been dropped.

- An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
- The TCP/IP Connection was aborted by Windows. This was possibly due to a data transmission timeout or protocol error.
- The virtual circuit was terminated due to a time-out or other failure. The application should close the socket as it is no longer usable.

SQL server error 11001 occurs when the SQL Server can't be found on Network.
This happens if the IP address is not reachable or the TCP port number is either not open or is not the correct port number or is blocked by a firewall

- This error mainly occurs when the SQL Server client can't connect to the server. This may happen when the client cannot resolve the name of the server or the name of the server is incorrect.

So we should check firewall list in Azure sql first.

Comment: Hi@Ahmad Akra  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. : )